# order in triggering events and functions

Tags: javascript

Is there a way to perform it in this order?

HTML:

```
<button type="button">Click!</button>
```

JS:

```
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
    eventFunction();
}, false);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
    location.hash = "changed";
    otherFunction();
});

function eventFunction() {
    console.log('first');
}

function otherFunction() {
    console.log('second');
}
```

here is jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/texzj2uv/1/

Comment: It won't fire any other events until the handler of `click` have finished its execution, so, no. It's not an events order problem. Your only option would be to call `eventFunction` and build a mechanism to avoid double calls (if you aleady called it, ignore `hashchanged` once).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just call `otherFunction` asynchronously:

```js
window.addEventListener("hashchange", function() {
  eventFunction();
}, false);

document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  location.hash = "changed";
  setTimeout(otherFunction, 0);
});

function eventFunction() {
  console.log('first');
}

function otherFunction() {
  console.log('second');
}
```

```html
<button type="button">
Click!
</button>
```

What happens is when you call `location.hash = "changed";` the browser pushes an event handler on the queue and then continues with the call stack. If you call `otherFunction()` right away, it will be on the call stack and will be called before anything on the queue. Calling it like `setTimeout(otherFunction, 0)` pushes it on the queue behind the event handler.

There is a great video explaining javascript loop, call stack and queue: [Philip Roberts: What the heck is the event loop anyway? | JSConf EU 2014](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ)

Comment: It might work, but you shouldn't take for granted that the browser will process the `hashchange` event before the 1ms interval.

Comment: Additional info for the OP:This works because js eventhandlers are pushed onto the qeue and are executed, when the browsers thread is empty. Trough calling setTimeout youre pushing the second call onto the qeue too, making both executing in order.

Comment: @Gabriel the 4ms interval. Also have a look at js Qeueing technique

Comment: Thanks @Jonasw! I've added clarifications.

Comment: @Gabriel https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#Reasons_for_delays_longer_than_specified

Comment: @Gabriel you don't need an timeout length at all, and you should definitely nor rely on it. the reason to use set Timeout is to push execution to the end of the que

Answer (score 3):

use setTimeout or setImmediate to push the second call to the end of the execution que. The problem is that the event is added to the end of the current que, so you need either call the first function directly, or push the second code execution to the end of the que.

```
document.querySelector('button').addEventListener('click', function() {
  location.hash = "changed";
  setTimeout(otherFunction);
});
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/texzj2uv/2/

There is probably a better to handle things depending on what you are trying to do though. Can you post more info one WHY you need the code executed in that order?

Comment: @Jonasw actually can take 3 arguments. if you leave the second argument out, which is the argument for the minimum timeout length, it defaults to a value of 0.

Comment: it is for any HTML5 compatible browsers. if you need to support one of the dumb ones, like probably IE 8 and below, the code would have to be `setTimeout(otherFunction, 0)`

Comment: fair, though all arguments after the second one are really just one collection of argument to be passed to the first argument